# Load MongoEngine document from inside class

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Is there a way to load a MongoDB document from within the class using MongoEngine? I'm currently using a loader function:

```
def load_user(username):
    user = User.objects(username=username).first()
    return user
```

This works, but it would be great if the relevant code could all be contained inside the class:

```
class User(mongoengine.Document):
    username = mongoengine.StringField()
    full_name = mongoengine.StringField()
    email = mongoengine.StringField()

    meta = {
        'db_alias': 'default',
        'collection': 'users'
    }

    def load(self, username)
        self = User.objects(username=username).first()

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).save(**kwargs)
```

Obviously, assigning to `self` doesn't work, as it only replaces the variable `self`. Also, if I just replace all the class properties by the ones loaded to a separate variable, I would be creating a new document if I tried to save it, so that doesn't seem like a viable solution either.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a classmethod

```py
    @classmethod
    def load(cls, username):
        return cls.objects(username=username).first()
```

Then you can use it directly from the class:

```py
User.load('some_user')
```

Comment: Wow, so simple! Thank you so much!!